# How to make Ubuntu use both graphic cards

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I have a desktop with AMD Radeon 6670 and the integrated intel graphics card. I want my computer to use both at the same time, already changed that in the BIOS and it works well on Windows so I suppose it's Ubuntu blocking my second monitor.

On the displays application, if I turn my second monitor off (the one that is with the dedicated card) and then I turn it on, it works like a charm, but the next time I reboot my computer, I have to follow the same steps.

I've read some solutions for NVIDIA graphic cards tinkering with Xorg or something like that, but none for AMD graphic cards. Is there a way to make Ubuntu use both at the same time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Using intel microcode and installing all the updates did the trick for me.